# Load service data and show in fullCalendar used AngularJS and FullCalendar

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

when using the events array (comment) it shows my calendar normally.
the problem is at the moment of loading the data that the service gives me, it does not load it before executing the uiConfig.

in $ scope.events = $ scope.JSON; I am trying to load the data (JSON string) that I receive from the service.

***execution positions***

1. call the service data
2. load the data to $ scope.events

   ```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Moment/moment.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/gcal.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
   <style>
   </style>
   <script>
       var app = angular.module('AppRODO', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']);
       app.controller('CtrlRODO', function ($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout, uiCalendarConfig) {

           var date = new Date();
           var d = date.getDate();
           var m = date.getMonth();
           var y = date.getFullYear();

           $scope.events = [];

           $http.get('/QA/Read_Data').then(function (response) {
               for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                   response.data[i]._id = i + 1;
                   response.data[i].start = new Date(parseInt(response.data[i].start.match(/\/Date\(([-0-9]*)\)\//)[1]));
                   response.data[i].end = new Date(parseInt(response.data[i].end.match(/\/Date\(([-0-9]*)\)\//)[1]));
               }
               $scope.JSON = response.data;

               $scope.events = $scope.JSON;
           });



           //          $scope.events = [
           //              { title: 'Solo un dia', start: new Date(y, m, 1), allDay: true, },
           //              { id: 999, title: 'Otra', start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0), allDay: true },
           //              { title: 'Rango de dias', start: new Date(y, m, 6, 19, 0), end: new Date(y, m, 10, 22, 30), allDay: true },
           //          ];

           $scope.eventsExt = {
               color: '#f00',
               events: [
                   { type: 'party', title: 'Finaliza', start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0), allDay: true },
                   { type: 'party', title: 'Finaliza 2', start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0), allDay: true },
                   { type: 'party', title: 'rodo', start: new Date(y, m, 28), end: new Date(y, m, 29), allDay: true }
               ]
           };

           $scope.Arque_Detail = function (date, jsEvent, view) {
               $scope.alertMessage = (date.title + ' was clicked ');
           };

           /* config object */
           $scope.uiConfig = {
               calendar: {
                   firstDay: 7,
                   height: 500,
                   lang: 'es',
                   editable: true,
                   header: {
                       left: 'title',
                       center: '',
                       right: 'today prev,next'
                   },
                   eventClick: $scope.Arque_Detail,
               }

           };

           /* event sources array*/
           $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventsExt];



           /* add custom event*/
           $scope.addEvent = function () {
               $scope.events.push({
                   title: 'RODO',
                   start: new Date(y, m, d),
                   end: new Date(y, m, d),
                   className: ['openSesame'], allDay: true
               });
           };
           /* remove event */
           $scope.remove = function (index) {
               $scope.events.splice(index, 1);
           };
       });
   </script>
   ```

***VIEW***

```
<body ng-app="AppRODO" ng-controller="CtrlRODO" ng-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="btn-group calTools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addEvent()"> Add Event </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <li ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy: 'start'">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <b> <input ng-model="e.title" /></b>
                        {{e.start | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}} - {{e.end | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}
                        <input type="button" class="btn-danger form-control" value="quitar" ng-click="remove($index)" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="alert-success calAlert" ng-show="alertMessage != undefined && alertMessage != ''">
                <h4>{{alertMessage}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <pre> {{JSON | json}}</pre>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <pre> {{events | json}}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is English-only. Please [edit] your title and second paragraph to use English, or, if you're more comfortable in Spanish, you may want to check out [es.so].

Comment: @HereticMonkey how is this now?

Comment: Bien ;) Regarding the question; `$scope.events` is going to be undefined until that response comes back. You may want to consider creating a function that does all of the stuff that depends on `$scope.events` and call it in the `then` function.

Comment: how should i do it?